# Unix code wanted to copy template file and replace strings in template file in the copied files

Tags: bash, sed

I have 2 files:

File_1.txt:

```
John
Mary
Harry
Bill
```

File_2.txt:

```
My name is ID, and I am on line NR of file 1.
```

I want to create four files that look like this:

Output_file_1.txt:

```
My name is John, and I am on line 1 of file 1.
```

Output_file_2.txt:

```
My name is Mary, and I am on line 2 of file 1.
```

Output_file_3.txt:

```
My name is Harry, and I am on line 3 of file 1.
```

Output_file_4.txt:

```
My name is Bill, and I am on line 4 of file 1.
```

Normally I would use the following sed command to do this:

```
for q in John Mary Harry Bill
do  
sed 's/ID/'${q}'/g' File_2.txt > Output_file.txt
done
```

But that would only replace the ID for the name, and not include the line nr of File_1.txt. Unfortunately, my bash skills don't go much further than that... Any tips or suggestions for a command that includes both file 1 and 2? I do need to include file 1, because actually the files are much larger than in this example, but I'm thinking I can figure the rest of the code out if I know how to do it with this hopefully simpler example... Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about:

```
n=1
while read q
  do  
  sed -e 's/ID/'${q}'/g' -e "s/NR/$n/" File_2.txt > Output_file_${n}.txt
  ((n++))
done < File_1.txt
```

See the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide on redirecting input to code blocks](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/redircb.html), and maybe [the section on double parentheses](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html#DBLPARENSREF) for further reading.

Comment: If I were doing this in bash, I'd make the template a here document, with `$ID` and `$NR`.

Comment: Thanks everyone! This was the one I ended up using, simple and effective!

Answer (score 3):

How about awk, instead?

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ cat file1
John
Mary
[ghoti@pc ~]$ cat file2
Harry
Bill
[ghoti@pc ~]$ cat merge.txt 
My name is %s, and I am on the line %s of file '%s'.
[ghoti@pc ~]$ cat doit.awk 
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
  while (getline line < "merge.txt") {
    fmt = fmt line "\n";
  }
}

{
  file="Output_File_" NR ".txt";
  printf(fmt, $1, FNR, FILENAME) > file;
}

[ghoti@pc ~]$ ./doit.awk file1 file2
[ghoti@pc ~]$ grep . Output_File*txt
Output_File_1.txt:My name is John, and I am on the line 1 of file 'file1'.
Output_File_2.txt:My name is Mary, and I am on the line 2 of file 'file1'.
Output_File_3.txt:My name is Harry, and I am on the line 1 of file 'file2'.
Output_File_4.txt:My name is Bill, and I am on the line 2 of file 'file2'.
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

If you really want your filenames to be numbered, we can do that too.

**What's going on here?**

The awk script BEGINs by reading in your merge.txt file and appending it to the variable "fmt", line by line (separated by newlines).  This makes `fmt` a printf-compatile format string.

Then, for every line in your input files (specified on the command line), an output file is selected (NR is the current record count spanning all files).  The printf() function replaces each `%s` in the fmt variable with one of its options.  Output is redirected to the appropriate file.

The `grep` just shows you all the files' contents with their filenames.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed '=' File_1.txt |
sed '1{x;s/^/'"$(<File_2.txt)"'/;x};N;s/\n/ /;G;s/^\(\S*\) \(\S*\)\n\(.*\)ID\(.*\)NR\(.*\)/echo "\3\2\4\1\5" >Output_file_\1.txt/' |
bash
```

Answer (score 1):

TXR:

```
$ txr merge.txr
My name is John, and I am on the line 1 of file1.
My name is Mary, and I am on the line 2 of file1.
My name is Harry, and I am on the line 3 of file1.
My name is Bill, and I am on the line 4 of file1.
```

`merge.txr:`

```
@(bind count @(range 1))
@(load "file2.txt")
@(next "file1.txt")
@(collect)
@name
@(template name @(pop count) "file1")
@(end)
```

`file2.txt:`

```
@(define template (ID NR FILE))
@(output)
My name is @ID, and I am on the line @NR of @FILE.
@(end)
@(end)
```

Comment: It would be useful to have an `@(include ...)` directive that loads source at read time. Then `template` could be defined inside `merge.txr` and just the `My name ...` line could be included, resulting in templates without any of the wrapping code. But if your template is large, the few lines are nothing.

Comment: `(range 1)` produces a lazy list, so there is no need to specify the end of the range.

Answer (score 1):

- Read the names into an array.
- get the array length
- iterate over the array

Test preparation:

```
echo "John
Mary
Harry
Bill
" > names
```

Names and numbers:

```
name=($(<names))
max=$(($(echo ${#name[*]})-1))
for i in $(seq 0 $max) ; do echo $i":"${name[i]}; done
```

with template:

```
for i in $(seq 0 $max) ; do echo "My name is ID, and I am on the line NR of file 1." | sed "s/ID/${name[i]}/g;s/NR/$((i+1))/g";   done 
My name is John, and I am on the line 1 of file 1.
My name is Mary, and I am on the line 2 of file 1.
My name is Harry, and I am on the line 3 of file 1.
My name is Bill, and I am on the line 4 of file 1.
```

Comment: are you serious? `echo "My name is ${name[i]} and I am on the line $i of file 1."` You've already rolled the template into your code; you might as well change it to be suited to the programming language you're using.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right, but I wanted to stay close to what Abdel already has. A remark, that the template could include the script would be alright, but maybe it doesn't fit in his greater context? Maybe changing name files.

Answer (score 1):

A little modification needed in your script.Thats it.

```
pearl.306> cat temp.sh
#!/bin/ksh

count=1
cat file1|while read line
do
sed -e "s/ID/${line}/g" -e "s/NR/${count}/g" File_2.txt > Output_file_${count}.txt
count=$(($count+1))
done
pearl.307>

pearl.303> temp.sh
pearl.304> ls -l Out*
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody        59 Mar 29 18:54 Output_file_1.txt
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody        58 Mar 29 18:54 Output_file_2.txt
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody        58 Mar 29 18:54 Output_file_3.txt
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody        58 Mar 29 18:54 Output_file_4.txt
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody        58 Mar 29 18:54 Output_file_5.txt
pearl.305> cat Out*
My name is linenumber11, and I am on the line 1 of file 1.
My name is linenumber2, and I am on the line 2 of file 1.
My name is linenumber1, and I am on the line 3 of file 1.
My name is linenumber4, and I am on the line 4 of file 1.
My name is linenumber6, and I am on the line 5 of file 1.
pearl306>
```